# WooCommerce - Create Products Programatically

Tags: posts, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm writing a plugin that will automatically import products via JSON API. I need to programatically create/update products.

I did a research and it seems everyone is using `wp_insert_post()` and `update_post_meta()` for this, ie [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503646/woocommerce-create-product-by-code) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75024/adding-a-variable-product-in-woocommerce-programatically)

However, I found that there's the [`class-wc-api-products`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/api/class-wc-api-products.php), where are various functions for adding/editing products and variations.

Is there any reason why people don't use something like:

```
$wc = new WC_API_Products();
$wc->create_product( $data );
```

It seems to me more future-proof to use native WC classes for this, am I wrong?

Comment: this is kind of question that you should ask the developer. Only he can tell you what is a stable API and what is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking, Woocommerce products are just another WordPress post object with a customized post type (which is `product` in this case). If you take a look at the `create_product` function inside `class-wc-api-products.php`, you'll see this line:

```
// Attempts to create the new product
$id = wp_insert_post( $new_product, true );
```

So the API ends up using `wp_insert_post` eventually. I guess you can do both but it's obviously using what WooCommerce API provides to create a WooCommerce product is a better way to go.